# Carrying Condoms while traveling to Dubai

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, legal, dubai, sex

I am traveling to Dubai in last week of May 2016, I wanted to know is it OK to carry condoms in my luggage or I'll be stopped at security check?

Comment: Its available in all general stores n super markets, so it should not be a problem..

Comment: [Protip: Don't import 720 of them](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2016-04-04/condoms-for-bali-hiv-group-prostitutes-denpasar-airport/7296804). (This happened with Indonesia, not the UAE, two separate countries, but the same principle applies).

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I would expect her actions to have caused trouble anywhere (if noticed--if you're a low risk passenger in a first world country the odds of an inspection are quite low.)  Those were being imported, they weren't for personal use.  You're normally required to declare anything you're importing and she didn't do so.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I would imagine if customs in any country found you were taking 720 of _anything_ into their country without declaring it they would question you.  They could very well have assumed she worked with the sex industry and was "smuggling" these in from a country where they were significantly cheaper, thereby avoiding local taxes.

Comment: @LorenPechtel I don't blame the Indonesian government for doing what it did. Sorry if "Protip" didn't make it obvious enough that 720 condoms may raise eyebrows anywhere.

Answer (score 48):

It's 100% OK to carry condoms. In fact, you will find them everywhere in Dubai (Pharmacies, supermarkets, etc.).

In case you are wondering (and I think you are since you asked this question), condoms are not a problem for both the Islamic and the Arabian cultures.

Source: I am both an Arab and a Muslim who lived in Dubai for 3 years in the past, and I still go there frequently, and I use condoms :)

Comment: In Indonesia, could large-scale condom importation fall foul of the Undang-undang Pornografi?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Despite the perception that Indonesia is uber conservative, birth control isn't frowned upon. They're even the leader in male-based pharmaceutical contraceptive development.

Comment: @StephenP. Indonesia doesn't really have a reputation as being uber conservative in Australia and if it doesn't have that reputation in its neighbour, I don't think any other country would have such a perception of the country.

Comment: This answer focuses on the legality of condoms, which is fine, but as a second concern aren't adultery and unmarried sex both criminal offences in UAE? Is there any danger at all of falling under suspicion if you're carrying condoms through customs but there's nobody in the country you can legally have sex with?

Comment: @SteveJessop no one cares, really.

Comment: From various answers I've read on this site, if you're not going around shouting, "I'm having extra-marital sex!" then nobody probably cares.

Comment: I lived in Dubai for many years. We knew a few couples who married to avoid complications associated with living together long-term, but that was for relationships spanning years. Anything shorter was exactly the same as any other country I've visited. To quote @heidel... "Nobody cares" (as long as you're not going out of your way to make a point).